# How to remove unnecessary space between Grid Rows of Material-UI?

Tags: reactjs, grid, material-ui

[image]I was trying to use material ui grid system but there is an awkward space occur when i use grid `direction='row'`.[image]

```
const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
    gridHome: {
        minHeight: '100vh',
        border: '2px solid red'
    },
    gridContent: {
        width: '100%',
        border: '2px solid black',
        textAlign: 'center'
    },
    title: {
        fontFamily: 'Dancing Script,Sans Serif,cursive',
    }
 }));

const NewUser = () => {
    const classes = useStyles();
    return (
        <React.Fragment>
            <Grid container direction='row' justify='center' alignItems='flex-start' className= 
            {classes.gridHome}>
                <Grid item xs={12} md={12} className={classes.gridContent}>
                    <Typography className={classes.title}>user</Typography>
                </Grid>
                <Grid item xs={12} md={12} className={classes.gridContent}>
                    <Typography className={classes.title}>Welcome User</Typography>
                </Grid>
            </Grid>
       </React.Fragment>
    );
}
```

Comment: Have you used the browser's inspect tool to see why so much space is there after `Grid` element?

Comment: yes i;ve but nothing is shown up

Comment: What do you men nothing is showing up? What CSS is being applied to the `Grid` element? This would be good information here. Or if you can provide a [Minimal. Complete, and Reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) codesandbox or similar for other to inspect, that would be great.

Comment: i've added browser tool checkup you can see that in box model nothing is shown like whether there is padding or margin between the components.

Comment: Yes, but *what* CSS is defined on these grid elements? What is getting `margin-top: 1vh;`?

Comment: I've applied margin-top='1vh' to the row elements of the grid so the when there is no awkward space between grid row, the should be at least 1vh of margin among grid rows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`minHeight: '100vh'` is the issue, because this Grid component is container and having display flex and "Grid item" component is having column width to 12...so first grid component will occupy entire width and hence second will be rendered in next row but container is flex so height of container will be divided in half and new Grid Item will be rendered from there ... causing this akward spacing.

This issue is very similar to [Material UI Grid List Rows with a big awkward gap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48036086/material-ui-grid-list-rows-with-a-big-awkward-gap?rq=1)